# FRAMESET set into center of page using CSS

Tags: css

I have the following code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    .mpanefset { top: 41px; left: 181px; position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100% }
</style>
</head>

<frameset class="mpanefset" cols="*">
    <frame src="action.html">
</frameset>
</html>
```

The code is meant to create a frame at location 181,41 with the src as action.html.

It loads the page, but does not position it at the location.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you only want to display _one single document_, then why are you using a frameset in the first place …?

Comment: My error. I will fix it in the code.

Comment: That’s not what I meant (and you can not have a `frame` without a surrounding `frameset`) – what I meant was, why are you using frames _at all_ here, why don’t you just let the user navigate to `action.html` directly, without anything “around it”?

Comment: Ahh, I see. I had just posted an SSCCE here. But in reality, there is a sidebar to the left and a headerbar to the top. There is a list of links in the sidebar which allow the user to switch to different urls in the frame.

Comment: Well, even for that, one usually doesn’t use framesets any more these days. Just put it all into one document. Use any server-side technique to include the parts that are the same into every page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't set **`<FRAMESET>`** tag on your custom defined location 181,41.

> **<FRAMESET>** is the alternate option for **<BODY>**

You are use any of one either **frameset** or **body**. This way you can not set frame on your defined positioning. keep it mind **frameset** start from **`top: 0`** and **`left:0`** position only. you have to set base on this positioning.

Frameset is well known for create a problems and be not search engines friendly, and is not well supported by all browsers. And now It's might be deprecated, so please don't use frameset.

Comment: What about iframe? Could I do what I need using iframe?

Comment: @Hele yes, it should work with an iframe.